# Thread-Safe Singleton implementation using .NET Lazy<T> seems to fail with XUnit

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class which has a `HashSet<T>` which is not thread-safe that I want to make thread-safe by using `lock` statements.

```
public sealed class DatabaseContextResolver
{
    #region Constructors

    DatabaseContextResolver()
    {
        _registeredContexts = new Hashtable();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    static readonly object ReadWriterLock = new object();

    static readonly Lazy<DatabaseContextResolver> DatabaseContextResolverInstantiator = new Lazy<DatabaseContextResolver>(() => new DatabaseContextResolver());

    internal static DatabaseContextResolver Instance => DatabaseContextResolverInstantiator.Value;

    readonly Hashtable _registeredContexts;

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void RegisterContext<TContext>(TContext context, string contextName)
        where TContext : class
    {
        context.ThrowIfNull(new MongoMigrationContextException("The context to register should not be null."));

        var namedContextTypeDependency = new NamedTypeDependency(contextName, typeof(TContext), context);

        if (_registeredContexts.ContainsKey(namedContextTypeDependency.ToString()))
        { throw new MongoMigrationDependencyException("The context cannot be registered because it's already registered.");  }

        lock (ReadWriterLock)
        {
            if (!_registeredContexts.ContainsKey(namedContextTypeDependency.ToString()))
            { _registeredContexts.Add(namedContextTypeDependency.ToString(), namedContextTypeDependency); }
            else
            { throw new MongoMigrationDependencyException("The context cannot be registered because it's already registered."); }
        }
    }

    internal void Clear()
    {
        _registeredContexts.Clear();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This class is made thread-safe by using `Lazy<T>` so I'm sure that only a single instance at a given time does exists. Is this assumption correct?

I do have a `clear()` methods which cleans the items in the `HashSet<T>`.
Now, I do have several xUnit tests which adds items to this class.

This is done with the following piece of code:

```
DatabaseContextResolver.Instance.RegisterContext(this, contextName);
```

How does it come when I run all my tests in xUnit that some of them does fail because an item with the same key in the `HashSet<T>` does already exists?

I tought my implementation was thread-safe?

Every xUnit class, which contains multiple tests affecting this, do implement `IDisposable` and calls the `clear()` method.

Comment: Why do you think that this is ```Lazy``` - issue? When Disposable called? Who guarantee, that no items can be added to hashset before its cleaned in previous tests?

Comment: To be honsest, it's a wild guess. Disposable is called after each test according to XUnit.

Comment: Hmm, seems like xUnit does run tests in different classes in parallel. If both classes accesses the same instance, an error could be raised. This can be resolved by using the `Collection` attribute in xUnit. This issue is now resolved.

Comment: Very useful, thx for sharing this :) I thought that it should not run tests in parallel, but no guarantee when Dispose will be called (like Dispose of prev Test may be called during Nest test running). Dont know how in XUnit, but in NUnit there special methods like Setup and Cleanup which should be called before/after each test.

Comment: Well, xUnit does not use `Setup`, nor `Cleanup` for tests. Instead, it uses class constructors and `IDisposable` for configuring tests.

Comment: Not obvious for me, but thx for clarifying.